# nftables: ct state rule produces "Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory"

Tags: debian, nftables

This is my /etc/nftables.conf

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f
flush ruleset

define wan = { eth0 }


table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;

            # allow everything from loopback interface
            iif lo accept comment "Accept any localhost traffic"
            # drop invalid connection attempts
            ct state invalid drop comment "Drop all invalid connection attempts"
            # allow established and related connections
            ct state established,related accept comment "Accept all traffic initiated by us"
            # allow explicitly allowed services/ports/protocols
            iif $wan tcp dport 22 accept comment "wan"
            # Apply extra (manual configured) rules
            # reject everything that has  not been accepted before
            reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited comment "Drop everything, which is not explicitly allowed"
    }
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;

            # allow everything from loopback interface
            iif lo accept comment "Accept any localhost traffic"
            # drop invalid connection attempts
            ct state invalid drop comment "Drop all invalid connection attempts"
            # Apply extra (manual configured) rules
            # reject everything that has  not been accepted before
            reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited comment "Drop everything, which is not explicitly allowed"
    }
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;

            # Apply extra (manual configured) rules
            }
}
```

This is what I get from `journalctl -u nftables.service`, after running `systemctl restart nftables.service`:

```
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net systemd[1]: Starting nftables...
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]: /etc/nftables.conf:14:13-33: Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]:             ct state invalid drop comment "Drop all invalid connection attempts"
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]: /etc/nftables.conf:16:13-47: Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]:             ct state established,related accept comment "Accept all traffic initiated by us"
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]: /etc/nftables.conf:21:13-51: Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]:             reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited comment "Drop everything, which is not explicitly allowed"
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]: /etc/nftables.conf:29:13-33: Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]:             ct state invalid drop comment "Drop all invalid connection attempts"
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]: /etc/nftables.conf:32:13-51: Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]:             reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited comment "Drop everything, which is not explicitly allowed"
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net nft[1682]:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net systemd[1]: nftables.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net systemd[1]: nftables.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 01 18:54:40 mydomain.net systemd[1]: Failed to start nftables.
```

When I comment the rules starting with "ct state" the service starts without an error. What is wrong here? The very same ruleset works fine on other machines.

System information:

OS: Debian 10

Kernel: 4.19.0-14-amd64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anybody else encountering this problem. Make sure:

1. The "netfilter" (and corresponding) kernel options are compiled either directly or as modules (grep -i netfilter /proc/config* or grep -i netfilter /boot/config*)
2. If the option have been compiled as modules, make sure you do not have sysctl option kernel.modules_disabled set to 1. (edit /etc/sysctl.conf)